# Is the element that a directive is declared on the ViewContainerRef for the Directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

When we constructor inject a `ViewContainerRef` in a directive, is the `ViewContainerRef` the element that the directive is declared on.

For example `<p [someDirective]="value"></p>`

And with the constructor injection:

```
constructor(vc: ViewContainerRef) {
    //The ViewContainerRef is bound to the p element
}
```

If we now do `vc.createComponent(...)` will that component be created inside the `p` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we constructor inject a ViewContainerRef in a directive, is the ViewContainerRef the element that the directive is declared on.

Yes, it references the same DOM element that the directive is referencing.

For example:

```
@Directive({...})
public constructor MyDirective {
    public cosntructor(el: ElementRef, view: ViewContainerRef) {
        console.log(el.nativeElement === view.element.nativeElement); // prints TRUE
    }
}
```

> If we now do vc.createComponent(...) will that component be created inside the p element?

Yes, because a `ViewContainerRef` has *many* views. It has the methods `length` and `get(index: number)` which allows you to get the `ViewRef` of the attached views.

So you can call `vc.createComponent(...)` multiple times and this `ViewContainerRef` will have more *views* added to it. The views that are added are the *host view* from the new component.

Comment: Nice touch with the `el.nativeElement === view.element.nativeElement`.  Thanks!